# This program that I am creating has to check to see if one number is a multiple of another number

Tags: java

This is what I have so far. If I put in a 4 for the first number and a 6 for the second it says that 4 is a multiple of 6,which is incorrect. I am not sure what is going on with it.

```
    System.out.print("\n Name =");
    String userName = console.readLine();

    System.out.print("\n First Number =");
    int firstNumber = console.readInt();

    System.out.print("\n Second Number =");
    int secondNumber = console.readInt();

    if (firstNumber / secondNumber == 0 || secondNumber / firstNumber == 0) {
        System.out.print("\n" + userName + "," + firstNumber + " is a multiple of " + secondNumber);
    }
    else {
        System.out.print("\n" + userName + "," + firstNumber + " is not a multiple of " + secondNumber);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check if a number is a multiple of an other with a modulo. Apply the module to the multiple you want to check, then simply confirm the remaining is equal to 0.

Example :

```
int number = 3;
System.out.println("isMultiple : " + (number % 3 == 0));
```

As for what is wrong in your code, you divide and check if equals to 0, this is not the correct way to do.

Look at this line

```
firstNumber / secondNumber == 0
```

Replace firstNumber with 6 and secondNumber with 3, it will return 2 which won't be equals to 0 even if 3 is a multiple of 6.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check if one number is a multiple of another is to use a modulo (remainder after division) operation. So, the code might look like:

```
if(firstNumber % secondNumber == 0) {
    // I'm a multiple!
}
```

Remember to check that `secondNumber` is not zero, otherwise you'll run a into division by zero!

Answer (score 1):

Divide an `int` by an `int` give an `int`, so `6/4 == 0`.

You can :

- Use the module as suggested by J.F. Savard
- Cast first and second number into `double` or `float`, and check if the result is equals to itself casted as `int` (or rounded)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is this check: `firstNumber / secondNumber == 0` and the other one there. This is not how you correctly check if a number divides another number.